# php xml nested namespace conversion to array

Tags: php, xml, json, parsing, namespaces

Is there a simple way to handle nested namespaces with XML conversion in php?  I am basically doing this:

```
$json = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml));
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

But when simplexml_load_string returns empty when the XML has nested namespaces.
here's the xml:
$xml=

```
'<ns1:XMLFault xmlns:ns1="cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">'; 
. '<ns1:faultstring xmlns:ns1="cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">Invalid instrument</ns1:faultstring>' 
. '<ns1:detail xmlns:ns1="cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">'; 
. '<ns2:exceptionDetails xmlns:ns2="order.services.ordermgmt.dh.om.com/">'; 
. '<errorCode>instrument.invalid</errorCode>' 
. '<errorMessage>Invalid instrument</errorMessage>' 
. '</ns2:exceptionDetails>' 
. '</ns1:detail>' 
. '</ns1:XMLFault>';
```

I am looking to convert this into json or php associative array (I am a novice with XML namespaces).

Comment: Calling `json_encode()` on the `SimpleXML` object that results from `simplexml_load_string()` seems very unlikely to be doing anything like what you want it to. Can you post the XML string, and the output you hope to be getting from this construct?

Comment: ^^^ /me is stunned to test and discover that with good and simplistic XML one actually can "cast" it to JSON directly from the SimpleXML object!

Comment: Please edit your post above with the XML, and the output you are aiming for. Don't post it in the comments.

Comment: Even before the json_encode, simplexml_load_string is returning empty.  Could it be something as simple as a missing flag?